# ArcGIS Web Mapping Service Extract By Mask Give 99999 Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arcgis-online, error-999999

The USDA used to provide four-band NAIP imagery as TIFF tiles for each township (6x6 miles) in the USA.  The 2013 data only available as an ArcGIS web-mapping service.  Not being a big fan of streaming data I would like to download these data for archiving and speedy rendering.  If I zoom to a township size extent and try *Data-Export Data* (limited by data frame extent) I get an error:

*Output raster dataset exceeds the size limitation (rows and columns) defined on the server. Export a smaller area by reducing the number of rows and columns...*

I can zoom into a section (1 mile x 1 mile) and execute a data export without error.

Being clever I thought I would automate the extraction of section tiles with Python.  As a test I have added a township-range-section feature class and selected a single section.  I then tried running *Extract by Mask* using the imagery and the selected section.  This returns the following error:

*ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The requested image exceeds the size limit.
Failed to execute (ExtractByMask).*

Since I can download a 1 mile by 1 mile tile manually this extent must be OK so  why does the Extract by Mask function fail?  Is there something about the WMS tile that cause the geoprocessor to fail to recognize the selected section when performing the Extract By Mask?